# Replacing AVPlayer with MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am trying to replace AVPlayer with MPMoviePlayerController as I want to be able to add an animation with transparent background to a view. The problem is the animation is not displaying with MPMoviePlayerController.

Please find my lines below. The first portion is with AVPlayer and it's work. The second is with MPMoviePlayerController and doesn't.

What the code does is it plays an animation and when this is done it is launching an action.

Code with AVPlayer (that works):

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:theAnimationFileName ofType:theString;

//NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
// First create an AVPlayerItem

AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:fileURL];

// Subscribe to the AVPlayerItem's DidPlayToEndTime notification.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];

// Pass the AVPlayerItem to a new player
controlledPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

AVPlayerLayer *animatedLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:controlledPlayer];


[animatedLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1024)];
[thisReplacementView.layer addSublayer: animatedLayer];


// Begin playback
[controlledPlayer play];
```

Code with MPMoviePlayerController (does not display anything):

```
NSString *moviePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:theString];

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeDefault;

moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1024);

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];


[thisReplacementView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

[moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://iOS.mp4"];
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
NSError *_error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &_error];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayer];

-(void)playbackFinishedCallback:(NSNotification *)notification{

    self.moviePlayer = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:self.moviePlayer];
}
- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.moviePlayer = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:self.moviePlayer];
    [self.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```